# How to add parameters to JSON in function in swift

Tags: json, swift, function, parameters

I have created one function for JSON parsing, which I am calling in every view controller, but i am unable to pass parameters from that function

i have created function in NSObject class:

```
func serviceCall(_ url: String, _ params:[String : Any], completion: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {

let url = URL(string: url)!
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

do {
    urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
    
        if let error = error {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            preconditionFailure("No error was received but we also don't have data...")
        }
        completion(data, nil)

}.resume()
}
}
```

**in registrationVC how to add parameters to this function**

my parameters for registration service:

```
struct RegData: Codable {
var jsonrpc: String
var params: PostReg
}

struct PostReg: Codable{
var email: String
var password: String
var device_id: String
}
```

while calling `serviceCall` function how to add parameters to it

if i call like this in button action

```
let url = "https://e/api/reg"
let jsonpostParameters: [String: Any] = RegData(jsonrpc: "2.0", params: (PostLogin(email: nameTf.text!, password: passwordTf.text!, device_id: "2")))

self.fetch(url, jsonpostParameters) { (data: Data?, error: Error?) in
    guard let dt = data else { return }
 // convert data to JSON
  print(dt)
```

error:

> cannot convert a value [String:Any] to RegData

how to add `RegData` to `serviceCall`, shall i change serviceCall `params` type? if yes how..

how add RegData to serviceCall to parse JSON

Comment: If you use `Codable`, you can pass a `Data` (you call  JSONEncoder beforehand), or you can use Generic, stating that you'll pass a `Codable` struct and can call `JSONEncoder` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this for decode data
//Here ResponceData is your codable class

```
 let dictData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)                                   
       
        let obj= try JSONDecoder().decode([ResponseData].self, from: dictData)
```